# Booting Laptop with external monitor stalls

Tags: ubuntu, boot, multi-monitor, laptop, monitors

Whenever I try to boot Ubuntu Linux with an external monitor attached to my laptop, it hangs after checking the battery state with the following message repeated several times:

```
...crtc_helper_set_config...
```

The only solution is to boot without the monitor attached, then attach it, and readjust my settings (turning off laptop screen, etc).

Some have told me this is a kernel issue, others just shrug.

Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: A stab in the dark: are there any related BIOS settings? [Oh, this bug report links it to `drm` and the Nouveau driver...and includes a debugging hint](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/nouveau/2011-May/008352.html), i.e, booting with `drm.debug=1` in the kernel command line

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no Bios settings related to my Graphics Card.  I have an Asus N53SN which has Optimus (meaning an Intel AND an Nvidia card).  And I use bumblebee to disable the nvidia card (to conserve power).

Comment: Hmm since this is pretty recent hardware, consider filing a bug report... I'm just not sure where to file it.  [Bumblebee](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bumblebee) is stated to be "under heavy development", maybe this is the place to go to (just guessing).